# How to inhibit communication with PS/2 keyboard with assembly?

Tags: windows, assembly, keyboard

> The host has ultimate control over the
>   bus and may inhibit communication at
>   any time by pulling the Clock line
>   low.

How to pull the Clock line **low** in assembly and **release** in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.  Not on Windows NT/2K/XP/Vista/7 anyway.

The instructions to do this kind of thing are blocked by the NT kernel.  It would be a security flaw if you had access to them (a virus could disable your keyboard for example).

If you *really* need to disable all communication over the PS/2 bus, you would have to write a driver.  You would probably want to do that in C, not assembler, since it is quite complicated.